# Better way to import files for webpack bundle size

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

**hooks/index.js**

```
export { default as useDialog } from './useDialog'
export { default as useCurrencies } from './useCurrencies'
export { default as useUser } from './useUser'
```

Let's imagine that I have 3 files in `hooks` folder (`useDialog`, `useCurrencies`, `useUser`) . I want to make the correct imports from this folder. Now I do imports like this :

```
import {useDialog} from 'hooks'
```

Is it correct way to import this file , or it is better to import it like `import useDialog from 'hooks/useDialog'` ? What is better for my bundle size ?

Comment: "What is better for my bundle size?" Have a try and compare the results. I don't think there is some always-true-suggestion on this

Comment: Aslo please note that `import {useDialog} from 'hooks'` and `import useDialog from 'hooks'` is different (if it not just a typo)

Comment: @JanStránský it isn't a typo, yes it is different and I want to know what is better

Comment: So it very much depends on what it actually `import`s (what is the default `export` of `hooks`).. Supposing you are using tree-shaking, the best approach (w.r.t. bundle size) should be (IMO) to `import` "as less as possible".

Answer (score 0):

You can try yourself and compare the bundle sizes on production from before and after. I'm gonna explain how to do it if anyone needs it.

First do these steps with the code importing from the index: `import {useDialog} from 'hooks'`

```
yarn build
serve -s build
```

Open the local address (http://localhost:5000/) on **incognito** mode. Then open Inspect -> Coverage.

At the bottom you can see the size. e.g: 1.2MB of 2.1MB (55%) used so far 964kB unused

Then change your code and import directly from the file: `import useDialog from 'hooks/useDialog'`, and repeat the build and check the size.

Maybe if the files are too small you are not going to notice a difference, but you will if there are any big files or files that imports a big external library.

I tried this comparison on my project and there was one file importing and using moment. I was not even using this component, but the bundle size was increased because I was importing another component from the same index.

Before I was always importing from a folder like `'hooks'`, but from now on I will always import directly from the file `'hooks/useDialog'`.

I'm just sharing my experience! Please, compare the bundles on your own projects!